# Appending to a list in a For-loop

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra

I am new to Mathematica. Here is my problem:

Given the matrix

$\qquad M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$,

sum the overlap (inner-product) of it's eigenvectors

$\qquad \bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}i \\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-i \\1 \end{pmatrix} \bigg\}$.

To this end, I first reshape to form arrays with correct dimensions. I am then able to generate and print the overlap values in the form of a 1x1 array for each overlap pair, but am then having difficulty appending the result to a list as can bee seen by the empty list `L2` in the output.

Can anyone advise me on what the problem is wrong with the attached code?

Appending Matrices to Lists

```
M = {{2, -1}, {1, 2}};
Eig = Eigenvectors[M]
Eval = Eigenvalues[M] ;
L1 = {};
L2 = {};

For[i = 1, i <= Length[M], i++,  
  AppendTo[L1, ArrayReshape[Eig[[i]], {Length[M], 1}]]]

For[i = 1, i <= Length[M], i++, 
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[M], j++ , 
    Print[Dot[ConjugateTranspose[L1[[i]]], L1[[j]]]]]] 

For[i = 1, i <= Length[Gd2], i++, 
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[Gd2], j++ , 
    Append[L2 , Dot[ConjugateTranspose[L1[[i]]], L1[[j]]]  ]]] 

Print[L1]
Print[L2]
```

> ```
> {{I, 1}, {-I, 1}}
> ```

During evaluation of In[2198]:= {{2}}
During evaluation of In[2198]:= {{0}}
During evaluation of In[2198]:= {{0}}
During evaluation of In[2198]:= {{2}}
During evaluation of In[2198]:= {{{I},{1}},{{-I},{1}}}
During evaluation of In[2198]:= {}

Comment: I don't understand exactly what "sum the overlap (inner-product) of it's eigenvectors" means, but if you want the inner (dot) product of its eigenvectors, then `m = {{2, -1}, {1, 2}}; Dot @@ Eigenvectors[m]`?

Comment: `For` and `AppendTo` is almost always very slow. I think, for example, your `For[i = 1, i <= Length[M], i++, AppendTo[L1, ArrayReshape[Eig[[i]], {Length[M], 1}]]]` is better stated as `L1 = List /@ Eig`. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396

Comment: But you've made one of the classic mistakes, I think: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/19804#19804

Comment: @MarcoB I want to save each overlap pair (as printed in my output) to a list.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thanks for your response, I think you are right. I come from a Python coding background hence still learning the Mathematica conventions Is there a  simpler way to do the main double for loop?

Comment: Mathematica has a number of looping and nesting functions that are often easier than traditional For or Do. Have a look at Map, MapThread, Fold, FoldList, among others.

Comment: @JohnDoe Could you specify exactly what the output(s) should be in this case? I cannot understand your intentions from your code.

Comment: You've used `Append` where I think you wanted `AppendTo`